# Bits and byte operation

Tags: c

```
/* Bit Masking */
/* Bit masking can be used to switch a character between lowercase and uppercase */
#define BIT_POS(N) ( 1U << (N) )
#define SET_FLAG(N, F) ( (N) |= (F) )
#define CLR_FLAG(N, F) ( (N) &= -(F) )
#define TST_FLAG(N, F) ( (N) & (F) )
#define BIT_RANGE(N, M) ( BIT_POS((M)+1 - (N))-1 << (N) )
#define BIT_SHIFTL(B, N) ( (unsigned)(B) << (N) )
#define BIT_SHIFTR(B, N) ( (unsigned)(B) >> (N) )
#define SET_MFLAG(N, F, V) ( CLR_FLAG(N, F), SET_FLAG(N, V) )
#define CLR_MFLAG(N, F) ( (N) &= ~(F) )
#define GET_MFLAG(N, F) ( (N) & (F) )

#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    unsigned char ascii_char = ‘A’; /* char = 8 bits only */
    int test_nbr = 10;
    printf(“Starting character = %c\n”, ascii_char);
    /* The 5th bit position determines if the character is
    uppercase or lowercase.
    5th bit = 0 - Uppercase
    5th bit = 1 - Lowercase */
    printf(“\nTurn 5th bit on = %c\n”, SET_FLAG(ascii_char, BIT_POS(5)) );
    printf(“Turn 5th bit off = %c\n\n”, CLR_FLAG(ascii_char, BIT_POS(5)) );
    printf(“Look at shifting bits\n”);
    printf(“=====================\n”);
    printf(“Current value = %d\n”, test_nbr);
    printf(“Shifting one position left = %d\n”,
    test_nbr = BIT_SHIFTL(test_nbr, 1) );
    printf(“Shifting two positions right = %d\n”,
    BIT_SHIFTR(test_nbr, 2) );
}
```

---

In the above code what does U mean in the

```
#define BIT_POS(N) ( 1U << (N) )
```

Also the above program compiles fine and output is

```
Starting character = A 

Turn 5th bit on = a  
Turn 5th bit off = ` 

Look at shifting bits
=====================
Current value = 10
Shifting one position left = 20
Shifting two positions right = 5
```

but when the 5th bit is turned off the result must be A instead of `(ascii 96)
please clarify.... 
Thank you.

Comment: ahh please format your code so that its readable. when editing this post, highlight all of the code and click the code button in the editor. the button that has "101010" on it.

Comment: @jordanstephens: I took the liberty of doing just that.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman, thanks I can't edit posts...

Answer (score 2):

The U means that '1' is an unsigned int, as opposed to a potentially signed int.

See [here](http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/constants.html).

As to the other problem; I'd speculate that the - in CLR_FLAG is causing the problem; try using a '~' (bit-wise not). Have not tested this though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
#define CLR_FLAG(N, F) ( (N) &= -(F) )
```

The `CLR_FLAG` macro does a bitwise-and of `N` and `-F`.  That is, `N` and minus-`F`.  What you really want to do is use the bitwise one's complement of `F`:

```
#define CLR_FLAG(N, F) ( (N) &= ~(F) )
```

Note that now I use `~F`.  The `~` operator performs bitwise `not`.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to change a character between uppercase and lowercase, you should not do it this way.  Use [toupper()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/toupper/)/[tolower()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/tolower/) instead.  By using those routines your intent is much more clear, and any locale specific differences on what is an upper/lowercase character are taken into account.